# Using config.js of ckeditor failed in jsp

Tags: jsp, ckeditor

I have downloaded the ckeditor_4.4.7_standard.zip and used it in my jsp with default settings.Now I want to do some changes in the config.js to get an ideal style but it does no effect.Then I try changing the settings in the jsp directly and it do effect.Finally I try editing other config.js named myconfig.js and use it in my jsp and it does no effect.I wonder how it come out?

using config.js(does no effect)

```
     ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"</script>
 ...
<textarea class="form-control" name="editor" id="editor"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor');</script>
...
```

using myconfi.js(does no effect)

```
     ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"</script>
 ...
<textarea class="form-control" name="editor" id="editor"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor',{customConfig:'static/js/ckeditor/myconfig.js'});</script>
...
```

using setting in the jsp directly(does effect)

```
     ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"</script>
 ...
<textarea class="form-control" name="editor" id="editor"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor',{
height:['430px']
});</script>
...
```

In config.js and myconfig.js I test by adding config.height='900px'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your browser cache. You should be doing it every time you change some JavaScript, CSS etc. files as these are extensively cached by the browsers.